# JS, Angular, AJAX : how to mix those three?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs

I would like to use an AJAX function to import JSON data from a PHP webpage, and then, to use it in an Angular JS controller. The problem is, nothing is working.

Here is my code :

```
(function(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "ajax/get_pal.php?type=populars&page=";
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      pal = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  var app = angular.module('palMod', []);
  app.controller('PalController', function(){
    this.prod = pal;
  });
})();
```

I'm still a beginner in AngularJS, but I'm totally lost here. What I'm doing wrong ?

get_pal.php send something like that : (with some datas, of course)

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Test","list":"[]","date_post":""}, ......]
```

Comment: read doc, angular is js, and ajax is in $http

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: btw you should also take a look at $q for async reqs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix up plain ajax with angularjs. Angularjs gives method to make ajax calls.
Use $http to make calls.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.websitename.com/file.php")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.records;
});
});
```

Comment: Mate you forgot to inject the $http module, but still you get my upvote!

Comment: Thanks for the example !
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

@Bob0t : Where do you put $q ?

Comment: @Iksen have you injected the module? same code but on the [] you have to insert '$http', the answer doesn't have that currently.

Comment: @Iksen $q is like $http, its a service, so you have to import it. See doc for examples. This will help you to deal with big data loadings and timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $http module to achiev what you want. You can read the documentation of it in here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Hope this helps!

P.S: Don't forget to inject the module.

(Example: var app = angular.module('MyCtrl',['$http']);

Comment: using $http needs most of the time : [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for async requests